# oauth2 to read & update google sheets from swift3 for ios app

Tags: ios, swift3, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use oauth2 for google sheets from swift3, I started with cocopods and able to get information from google sheets with my id, didn't try updating yet.  But I need to use it in my IOS app, so I need make it independent of login, that's why I am trying to use oauth2.  Will someone give me steps or point me in that direction.  Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to use the Google Sheets API without their SignIn SDK ?

Comment: irrespective of user has access to my google sheets or not, they should be able to use my app.  I don't want to make my spreadsheet public or I want to give access to everyone that uses my app.  I believe I am clear.  if this can be implemented using something else also that works for me.